# How to embed Qt Quick code in C++?

Tags: qt, qt-quick

I'm creating a rather complicated user interface in Qt. I'm using C++ everywhere but after finding out about the amazing Qt Quick, I was thinking if there's a way I could embed Qt Quick  in basic C++ interface resulting in a **Hybrid UI**?

Answer (score 0):

"Embed qt quick code in c++" sounds like a very bad idea. That was exactly the purpose qt quick was created in the first place - separate logic from UI. Just focus on implementing the performance critical parts of your code in a logic core and use signals, slots and properties to create UI to work with that logic core with QML. The idea is that both the logic core and the UI are abstracted enough to be completely independent on eachother besides the data bindings.

If what you mean to ask is if you can "embed" QML files into the executable - yes, QML files can be used from standard Qt resource files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing the .qml file with qml code, and then loading it using the **QQuickView** class.

Example from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickview.html):

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqmlfile.qml"));
view->show();
```

For more advanced use and QtQuick <-> C++ integration look at [this presentation](https://qt.digia.com/Global/Images/Qt/Files/QtEssentialsQtQuick/1/qml-cpp-integration.pdf)

Comment: This is just the standard boiler plate code automatically generated for a new qt quick application.